# Jquery button event click issue

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have jquery button which need click event to enable the datatable.Please look into below code advise.

```
       jQuery( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({ 
 autoOpen: false,
 height: 500,
 width: 750,
 modal: true,
 buttons : {
 "Search" : function() {
 jQuery.ajax({type : 'POST',
 url : ' <s:url action="part" method="list" /> '
 })
  }
    }
 });
```

Now i need to write Search button click event.

```
jQuery("Search").click(function() { Hello });
```

Above event is not triggering.What is the issue here ?

Comment: jQuery("Search") should probably be this jQuery("#Search")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to attach an event handler to the "Search" button using `.click()`. The function that gets executed when the button is clicked is the function you specify in the "buttons" option. In your case, the function that gets executed when the "Search" button is clicked is:

```
function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : '<s:url action="part" method="list" />'
    })
}
```

Just change that function to what you want it to be.

Answer (score 2):

It should be either

```
//really concise and great if you're not passing parameters
jQuery("#Search").on('click', Hello);
```

or

```
// you had Hello instead of Hello();
jQuery("#Search").on('click', function() { Hello(); });
```

Use **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** for dynamic code.

Comment: jQuery("#Search").click(function() {alert("hello");}); which is not working.

Comment: Well the are you sure you have an element with id Search? Also an id should be unique, are you sure you only have one of these?

Comment: No, there is no id search. I'm creating button in jquery above function buttons : { "Search" : function() {... So there is no id search.

Comment: Got it; if you're adding elements at runtime, you need .on() because .click() only binds when the handler is first evaluated. See edit.

Comment: yes , url : ' <s:url action="part" method="list" /> ' for calling struts action class to pull the data from DB , after need to display those values in datatable.

Comment: nope , its not working.There is no id search for this button.then how to get that button trigger here ?

Comment: I think you should put this in a jsFiddle so we can debug it; the syntax is correct so the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This selector `jQuery("Search")` is searching for an element of `Search`. If `Search` is an ID you need to use the ID `#` selector:

```
jQuery("#Search").click(function() { console.log("hello"); });
```

Also, inside your click function, I'm not sure what `Hello` is, but I presume you wanted an alert or a log.

Comment: buttons : {
 "Search" : function() { its button created through jquery.so you can get id of search ?